# Trouble getting Angular Google Map AGM to work with Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps, angular11, agm

I installed agm/core using npm like this:

```
npm install @agm/core
```

The following warnings were displayed:

```
npm WARN @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I continued nevertheless and imported AgmCoreModule into AppModule as per docs like this:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'MY MAP KEY',
      libraries: ['places']
    })
```

However, when trying to serve the app with **ng serve**, the following errors occur:

```
Error: node_modules/@agm/core/lib/services/google-maps-api-wrapper.d.ts:50:41 - error TS2314: Generic type 'MapHandlerMap<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
50     subscribeToMapEvent<N extends keyof google.maps.MapHandlerMap>(eventName: N): Observable<google.maps.MapHandlerMap[N]>;
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@agm/core/lib/services/google-maps-api-wrapper.d.ts:50:94 - error TS2314: Generic type 'MapHandlerMap<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
50     subscribeToMapEvent<N extends keyof google.maps.MapHandlerMap>(eventName: N): Observable<google.maps.MapHandlerMap[N]>;
                                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@agm/core/lib/services/managers/marker-manager.d.ts:25:93 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MarkerMouseEventNames'.

25     createEventObservable<T extends (google.maps.MouseEvent | void)>(eventName: google.maps.MarkerMouseEventNames | google.maps.MarkerChangeOptionEventNames, marker: AgmMarker): Observable<T>;
                                                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@agm/core/lib/services/managers/marker-manager.d.ts:25:129 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MarkerChangeOptionEventNames'.39m

25     createEventObservable<T extends (google.maps.MouseEvent | void)>(eventName: google.maps.MarkerMouseEventNames | google.maps.MarkerChangeOptionEventNames, marker: AgmMarker): Observable<T>;
```

I have this working on an existing Angular 7 application already. But I am trying to upgrade to Angular 11 and having problems getting @agm/core to work.

I am also aware of an official Angular google-map component, but I need to use the autocomplete feature that seems to integrate well with agm, and couldn't find any docs to do this with the google-map component.

Has anyone managed to successfully use **@agm/core** with Angular 11?
Help and suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 48):

I had the same issue and I found in other forums where rolling back the version of the googlemaps fixed it.  I ran the following command and I was able to see it work as expected.

```
npm i @types/googlemaps@3.39.13 --save-dev
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you used this in Angular 11? I still cant get agm/core to install in Angular 11

Comment: Worked with Angular 12.

Comment: Just to be clear, does this library work the same as AGM?

Comment: Hey, @jjaur's did you try and get any results? Because I am having the same issue with agm.
-- edited
Also getting error with `npm i @types/googlemaps@3.39.13 --save-dev`

Comment: Hey, @Satrughna i had a result while using the solution proposed. It is working. Hope it will help you

Comment: @Reid I ma using Angular 12 as well with googlemaps@3.39.13 but still having the issue. Did you do anything aside?

Answer (score 9):

Sorry for late response. I opted to use the **google-map** component from Angular that works well in Angular 11+

You can find more info here:
https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps#readme

Thank you for all the comments and suggestions for the problem with AGM.
However, I stopped using AGM in favour of the google-map component. It made more sense since it is supported directly in Angular. So unfortunately I am unable to confirm whether the suggested solutions work for AGM.

I do recommend using google-map instead if you experience problems with AGM in Angular 11+

Answer (score 1):

AGM may not be working on angular 11 or later.

Do a `ng --version` to take a look at your ng client version

(my angular cli version is 13.3.8 a few version below the latest, at the time of writing) and then
visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps
and click the xyz Versions tabs to find all the versions, and select the one matches your major.minor version. In my case the closest I can find  was 13.3.9 and click that link to get more information, mine suggest to use the below code (near the top right hand corner)..happy coding

```
npm i @angular/google-maps@13.3.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your advice and answers, just out of interest sake I got it working with angular 11 by forcing the install, got a lot of warnings, but it works:

```
npm install @agm/core -f
```

Here is the warnings:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm WARN Found: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/common
npm WARN   peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm WARN     peer @angular/cdk@"11.2.13" from @angular/material@11.2.13
npm WARN     node_modules/@angular/material
npm WARN     1 more (the root project)
npm WARN   11 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/common@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm WARN node_modules/@agm/core
npm WARN   @agm/core@"*" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@10.2.5
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/common
npm WARN   peer @angular/common@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@agm/core
npm WARN     @agm/core@"*" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm WARN Found: @angular/core@11.2.14
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/core
npm WARN   peer @angular/core@"11.2.14" from @angular/animations@11.2.14
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm WARN     peer @angular/animations@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/material@11.2.13
npm WARN     node_modules/@angular/material
npm WARN     3 more (@angular/platform-browser, ngx-bootstrap, the root project)
npm WARN   14 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common, @angular/forms, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/core@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm WARN node_modules/@agm/core
npm WARN   @agm/core@"*" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@10.2.5
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/core
npm WARN   peer @angular/core@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@agm/core
npm WARN     @agm/core@"*" from the root project
```

PS I noticed that the [@agm/core](https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps) repo has been forked quite a bit, and some of them seem to resolve this problem.